# Replace row header with images

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on a worksheet which has long header names. I want to display table compactly using icon images instead of using header labels. Say I have a column named "Population Density" in a table. I would like a population icon to show up instead of full label.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the closest you could come with this is using [Unicode Emoji](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/emoticons/) in a column alias.

For measure values, right click the header and click "Edit Alias", then paste the unicode emoji into the text box.

For dimensions, right click the pill and click "Edit in Shelf". Move the cursor to the beginning of the line and press Shift+Enter to add a new line above, then press the up arrow. Type `//` on the new line, paste the selected unicode emoji, and hit Enter.